# Clear Beer Hazy After Carbonation

Tags: kegging, cloudy

I made a Belgium Grisette, which I have made before. This time I let it sit in the keg under CO2 for a couple of months, as I was out of town.  When I returned, I opened the keg, beer was very, very clear and I racked it into two 2.5 Gallon kegs, put them under CO2 and carbed one to the recommended volume.  In a week or so, I drew a beer, good frothy white head, decent taste, but very cloudy.  The frig was cold, about 38F.

So, I have never had this happen with a kegged beer.  Chill Haze or issue with temperature or time spent in the keg prior to carbing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the first couple pints of the sludge from keg fining. If the later pints are clear, then this is the case.

Or chill haze, If the beer clears in a glass once at room temp it's chill haze.